# Property 'validateRegister' does not exist on type 'ValidateService'.)

Tags: angular, typescript

I am following a tutorial on YouTube and unfortunately what the instructor is doing doesn't work for me. I am using Angular 2

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {ValidateService} from '../../services/validate.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-register',
  templateUrl: './register.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./register.component.css']
})
export class RegisterComponent implements OnInit {

  name: String;
  username: String;
  email: String;
  password: String;

  constructor(private validateService: ValidateService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  onRegisterSubmit() {
    const user = {
        name: this.name,
        username: this.username,
        email: this.email,
        password: this.password
    };
      // Required fields

      // Required Fields
    if(!this.validateService.validateRegister(user)){
        console.log("fill in all fields");
      return false;
    }

  }

}
```

---

ValidateService (./services/validate.service.ts)

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class ValidateService {

  constructor() { }

  // Ensures all fields are filled out.
  validateRegister(user) {
    if (user.name == undefined || user.username == undefined || user.email == undefined || user.password == undefined) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
  }

  // Makes sure email is in correct format
  validateEmail(email) {
    const re = /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
    return re.test(email);
  }

}
```

---

Error: Property 'validateRegister' does not exist on type 'ValidateService'.)

I see that it's showing validateRegister not being recognized but I cannot figure out why it is.

```
// Modules
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import {RouterModule, Routes} from '@angular/router';


// Componenets
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { NavbarComponent } from './components/navbar/navbar.component';
import { LoginComponent } from './components/login/login.component';
import { RegisterComponent } from './components/register/register.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './components/home/home.component';
import { DashboardComponent } from './components/dashboard/dashboard.component';
import { ProfileComponent } from './components/profile/profile.component';

// Services
import {ValidateService} from './services/validate.service';

const appRoutes: Routes = [
  {path: '', component: HomeComponent},
  {path: 'register', component: RegisterComponent},
  {path: 'login', component: LoginComponent},
  {path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent},
  {path: 'profile', component: ProfileComponent}
];

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    NavbarComponent,
    LoginComponent,
    RegisterComponent,
    HomeComponent,
    DashboardComponent,
    ProfileComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes)
  ],
  providers: [ValidateService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Sorry but not sorry, I just figured it out. Had to restart the server. I thought Angular was saving as I was changing :P Thanks for the help folks!

Comment: where do you provide `ValidateService` ?

Comment: app.module.ts in the providers array. Just updated code to display it :)

Comment: can you display a stacktrace?

Comment: ERROR in /home/jd/Documents/development/mean-auth/angular-src/src/app/components/register/register.component.ts (31,30): Property 'validateRegister' does not exist on type 'ValidateService'.)

Comment: That is the only output in the console